# The proxychains equivalent for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, proxy, socks5

I'm already using SSH tunneling by `ssh -D 9058 username@5*.**.1*1.1*`. I need software on Windows to use this tunnel for specific applications or even for the whole system. It should be free and preferably open source.

1. [proxychains.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1526831/571029) didn't work for me for some reason.
2. [proxycap](https://serverfault.com/questions/541279/proxychains-equivalent-for-windows#comment623005_541280) is not free.
3. [proxifier](https://superuser.com/a/1342060/571029) that I'm currently using. It works great. But It's not free:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used this approach to set up a socks proxy on Windows 10. The whole system would be proxied. It works for me:

https://superuser.com/a/1618473/571029